# New uploaded images not found (404) after MAMP upgrade

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I was previously using [MAMP 4.5](https://www.mamp.info/en/) on Mac OS High Sierra. I've been working on a WordPress project which lives under `MAMP/htdocs/project`.

After upgrading to MAMP 5.0, any new images which are added to my theme image directory cannot be found. E.g. if I add a new image to `wp-content/themes/theme/img/new.svg`, the browser console says it cannot be found. Going directly to the url within the browser also throws up a 404.

If I visit the `/img` directory in the browser, it doesn't reflect the newer images I recently added. This might give us some clues.

[image: Directory via browser]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is simple.

When MAMP installs a new version, it copies your website files to a new directory. I had the old directory still open which meant I wasn't seeing the new files via the browser.

[image: Facepalm]